# Find the subspace $S\cap T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$, $S$ is a subspace of all the vectors with the first coordinate $0$, and $T$ is a subspace generated by the vectors $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,3,0)$. Find the subspace $S \cap T$.

Can someone help me with this problem? I have an exam tomorrow and I can't quite understand this problem.

Comment: Hint: $(2,3,0)-2\cdot (1,1,1)$ is a vector in $T$ since it is a linear combination of the basis vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take basis of both subspaces:

$$S=\text{Span}_{\Bbb R}\left\{\,\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}\;,\;\;T=\text{Span}_{\Bbb R}\left\{\,\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\0\end{pmatrix}\;\,\right\}$$

and now form the $\;3\times4\;$ corresponding matrix and reduce it by tows:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1\\
2&3&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1\\
0&1&\!-2\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1\\
0&1&\!-2\\
0&0&2\\
0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1\\
0&1&\!-2\\
0&0&2\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

From the above we get $\;\dim \left(S+T\right)=3\;$, and thus $\;\dim(S\cap T)=1\;$ Why? Be sure you can explain/justify all this).

Observe also that

$$\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\0\end{pmatrix}-2\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\in S\ldots$$

Try to take it from here...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

A generic element from the second subspace can be written as $$\vec v=t(1,1,1)+u(2,3,0)$$

Find for which values of $t$ and $u$ the first coordinate vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

Here a general method: set $S =  \mathrm{Span}\{(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ and $T = \mathrm{Span}\{(1,1,1),(2,3,0)\}$. A vector in the intersection can be written as a linear combination in two ways as follows:
$$a(0,1,0)+b(0,0,1) = c(1,1,1)+d(2,3,0).$$
This equality implies 
$$
\begin{cases}
-c-2d = 0 \\
a-c-3d = 0 \\
b-c = 0,
\end{cases}
$$
namely $b = c, d = -\frac{c}{2}$ and thus $a = -\frac{c}{2}$. So the intersection is given by a one-dimensional space containing vectors of the form
$$a(0,1,0)+b(0,0,1) = -\frac{c}{2}(0,1,0)+c(0,0,1) = c\left(0,-\frac{1}{2},1\right), c \in \mathbb{R}.$$